# manifest permissions change when rolling out new app version

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

We had 3 permissions - ver 1.0 - in manifest with app of about 10k+ downloads.

We added 1 permission - ver 1.1 - (not knowing that it will take down the "automatic update" checkbox)
Update did not happen automatically for the users.

**Questions :**

1. If we roll out new ver 1.2 with the same code but remove permission added in 1.1 will users be updated automatically from 1.0 to 1.2 ?
2. Will reverting the app to 1.0 release bring back the "automatic update" checkbox for users ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

official response from google about this :

"Please note that changing permissions between app versions will not prevent users from being notified that an update is available. The only difference is that users must manually accept the new permission requirements when Google Play notifies them that the update is available. In other words, the update will not be automatically installed, but users will still be notified.

In this particular case, any users that have updated to the new version have already accepted the change in permissions. Furthermore, reverting the permissions in a future update will require the updated users to accept the new permissions again (likely not a problem since they accepted the previous change). As well, any users who did not accept the permission change and remained on the older version will be automatically updated to the newest version if the permissions are identical."

Comment: Could you please give the Google's official response link. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No.
If the permissions of the app were changed, the user must always confirm the update.